# End range of let definition in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I had a problem with defining multiple objects (functions, variables etc.)

I tried to reproduce the problem here:

```
let myfunction () = 
  if true then Printf.printf "true"
  else
    Printf.printf "false"

let x = 1 in Printf.printf "%d" x
```

It gives me a syntax error:

```
7 | let x = 1 in Printf.printf "%d" x
              ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

I was wondering why, since if I defined `x`, then defined `myfunction` there would be no problem.

I recognize that putting `;;` before defining `x` solves the problem, but you're not supposed to use double semi-colon.

I tried adding a begin / end, wrapping the if / else statement with parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace doesn't mean *much* to an OCaml program.

What you wrote is the same as writing the following, and you shouldn't be surprised to see that create an error.

```
let myfunction () = 
  if true then Printf.printf "true"
  else
    Printf.printf "false" let x = 1 in Printf.printf "%d" x
```

Your indentation suggests the `let x = 1 in ...` is not meant to be part of the `myfunction` function. To remedy this, you might make this a top level binding. Your `x` is *local* to that expression.

```
let myfunction () = 
  if true then Printf.printf "true"
  else
    Printf.printf "false"

let () =
  let x = 1 in 
  Printf.printf "%d" x
```

As an aside, from the way you're using `Printf.printf` you may just wish to use `print_string` and `print_int` instead.

```
let myfunction () = 
  print_string (if true then "true" else "false")

let () =
  let x = 1 in 
  print_int x
```